# How to simplify complicated template declarations

Tags: c++, c++11

For example I would like to simplify the `std::tr1::shared_pointer` template class. I would like to have an alias for `std::tr1::shared_pointer`.

But this doesn't work:

```
#include <tr1/memory>

template <class T>
class SharedPointer : public std::tr1::shared_ptr<T>
{
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SharedPointer<int> test(new int(5));
    return 0;
}
```

Since the constructors are not inherited.

Is there a pattern to solve this?

Comment: Why are you still using `tr1`.

Comment: On a side note, it's more than a little bizarre to use anything in `std::tr1` with a C++11 compiler...

Comment: Probably still on VS2008 or something.  Not everybody can upgrade to the newest compilers, even relatively not often.  Sad, but it's how it is sometimes.

Comment: @Kevin : The OP tagged this `c++11` though.

Comment: @ildjarn: What should he have tagged it as? C++0x?

Comment: I am using gcc. Please, where can I find the shared_ptr?

Comment: @Mehrdad : `c++` + `tr1` most likely. Or `c++03`. But because it's tagged `c++11`, the OP got a potentially-useless C++11-specific answer.

Comment: @ildjarn: Honestly, all that would do is get fewer people to read his post...

Comment: @Mehrdad : So what? If the OP gets a useless answer because they mistagged their own question, what does it matter if more people read it?

Comment: @Martin : Assuming a relatively recent version of GCC (you didn't mention), invoke g++ with `-std=c++0x`, `#include <memory>`, and use `std::shared_ptr<>`.

Comment: @ildjarn: Why get a useless answer? I thought the whole point of TR1 was that it was intended to behave exactly as C++11 was intended to... and I haven't heard of any major changes that would affect a question like this.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik: What version of gcc are you using? If it's before GCC 4.7, my answer won't apply

Comment: @Mehrdad: The point of TR1 is to provide a preview of standard library that might have made it into the latest C++ standard. AFAIK, TR1 doesn't include any language update.

Comment: @Mehrdad : I don't think we're talking about the same thing. If the OP is using a C++03 compiler and mistagged this as C++11 because they happen to use `shared_ptr<>`, then the answer posted by Ken will not be useful. If the OP is using a C++11 compiler and is using things in namespace `std::tr1`, that's merely bizarre, as I said. What is confusing here? :-]

Comment: @ildjarn: I guess you're judging the tags by the compiler, I'm judging the tags by the library.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde, I am using gcc 4.6.3 and unfortunately it does not work, but it is valuable information for me anyway. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to alias it, a `using` declaration will create a true alias, rather than a subclass:

```
template<class T>
using SharedPointer = std::tr1::shared_ptr<T>;
```

### Edit

A method that should work on GCC 4.6.* compilers would be to make a wrapper function around the `std::tr1::shared_ptr<T>`. Since GCC 4.6.* supports the C++11 library, I've used that instead of TR1:

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::shared_ptr<T> make_shared_ptr(Args &&... args)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto test = make_shared_ptr<int>(new int(5));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So I replaced my declaration with the above, but I am getting an 

expected unqualified-id before 'using'

Error. I am using gcc 4.6.3 and I have enabled the  C++0x support, by adding the command-line parameter -std=c++0x.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik: GCC 4.6 doesn't support template aliases. To use this syntax, you must upgrade to GCC 4.7, using either the `std=c++0x` or `std=c++11` command-line parameter

Comment: @MartinDrozdik: Maybe try `template<class T> typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<T> SharedPointer;`? Though maybe GCC 4.6 doesn't support that either, not sure.

Comment: @Mehrdad: That's not valid C++. The `using` alias was invented to provide exactly that functionality.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde Oh lol never mind, I thought that's what they meant by "template typedefs".

Comment: The standard provides `std::make_shared`, which is kinda like your function, but actually far better since it can employ a great optimization. Read up on it.

Answer (score 5):

If you're not using C++11, then unfortunately the best you can do is:

```
template <class T>
struct SharedPointer
{
    typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<T> type;
};
```

Which has to be used as:

```
SharedPointer<int>::type x(new(int));
```

Comment: Thank you! This works for me, I just have to declare the typedef as public.

Comment: Ah, right, good point -- I just changed it to a `struct` which has the same effect with slightly less verbosity.

Comment: Wow, this is pretty ingenious. Using it is just about as clean as with  template aliases.

Comment: @Ken : Until you're inside of a template, and need to prefix it with `typename` every time. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn Inside a template (function or class), you can often get away with using a local `typedef`, so you only need to use `typename` prefix once.  But that's not always appropriate, and sometimes you do need to do a lot of `typename` prefixing.